# Find points in a multi-dimensional half cone

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, convex-cone

By knowing the opening angle, a point on a multi-dimensional half cone and the cone axis, is it possible to find any other point in that hypersurface?

For $2D$ half cones, it is enough to multiply the point by a scalar or/and reflect it with respect the cone axis.

What about for $3D$, $4D$,... half cones?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Seems to me that in your 2D example you know quite a bit more than just a point on the cone and the opening angle.

Comment: @amd Indeed, I know the cone axis. The question was edited. Thanks!